# I need to append 3 queries in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to append three queries and make them look like this:

```
HEADER1  HEADER2  HEADER3
-------------------------
Total1   Total2   Total3
```

I've tried `UNION`, but that returns the results of the queries in rows like this:

```
HEADER
------
total1
total2
total3
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It'd help to see the queries you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe something like:

```
select (select x1 from something1) as header1, 
(select x2 from something2) as header2, 
(select x3 from something3) as header3
from dual
```

Comment: You could use the first query as the main, and subselects for the other two -- rather than selecting from DUAL. I'd like to see the actual queries to determine if this is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting situation when you want to make something into a single row rather than multiple rows.  The easiest way is to do a sum() for each "column" and placing your where style clause in an IF() statement.

```
select sum(sumconstraints) as Header1, sum(sumconstraints) as Header2, etc... 

sumconstraints should be an IF(where clause for this total, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Seems like you are presuming all the queries are on the same table or set of tables, which may not be the case.

Comment: This is a fair statement.  I was under the impression that it was from the same set of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes found the following to be a useful construct;

```
select sum(c1) Header1, sum(c2) Header2, sum(c3) Header3
from (
     select field c1, 0 c2, 0 c3
     from table1
     ) t1,
     (
     select 0, field, 0
     from table2
     ) t2
     (
     select 0,0,field
     from table3
     ) t3
[where clause and joins between t1,t2 and t3]
```

In the example I have assumed numeric values and used a sum.  The same approach can be used with strings by, for example, replacing the 0 with NULL and SUM with MAX.